# Is There a simple proof of $\displaystyle x+\sin(x)\geq 2\log(x+1)?$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $x>-1$ seems that

$$x+\sin x \geq 2\log{(x+1)}$$

but this looks like a coincidence, is there any simple proof of this inequality?

Comment: What is your method for this inequality!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):=x+\sin x$ and $g(x):=2\log(1+x)$. Then $$f(0)=g(0)=0,\quad f'(0)=g'(0)=2,\qquad f''(x)-g''(x)=-\sin x+{2\over(1+x)^2}\ .$$
It follows that $f''(x)-g''(x)>0$ for $-1<x\leq0$, hence the conjectured inequality is true when $-1<x\leq0$. Furthermore $f''(0)-g''(0)=2$ implies that $f-g$ is positive for $0<x\ll1$.

A look at the graphs of $f$ and $g$ then shows that near $x=4$ these two functions do not differ by much. For a full self-contained proof that in fact $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x>0$ we would need good estimates for $f$ and $g$ near $x=4$. I don't think the problem is worth so much analytic effort.